# Console settings not applied when running program via shortcut

Tags: windows-10, console, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1703

I have already configured my Windows Subsystem for Linux (`bash.exe`) to use a color table and a font like this:

[image: A]

And it looks OK when I type `bash.exe` in "Run" dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) or manually navigate to `%SystemRoot%\System32\` and double-click `bash.exe`.

But when I launch it via a shortcut, default settings are applied and it looks like this:

[image: B]

Which of course is not what I want.

Specifically, I'm clicking this item in my start menu:

[image: C]

Windows 10 Enterprise version 1703 (Build 15063.608) x64. Just in case, the settings in the shortcut looks fine:

[image: D]

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution and it's stable, albeit not the ideal.

Create a VBScript with the following content:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Shell
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Shell.Run "%SystemRoot%\system32\bash.exe"
```

Save it as `BashStart.vbs` and put it inside `%SystemRoot%\System32`. Then manually edit all shortcuts that you use so they point to `%SystemRoot%\System32\BashStart.vbs` instead of `%SystemRoot%\System32\bash.exe`. Now the Windows Subsystem for Linux shows up with the correct color palette and font.